# AWS ECS Restart service if not running latest image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, azure-devops, amazon-ecs

I'm setting up automated deployments using Azure DevOps to deploy to AWS ECS running services on an EC2 instance (not Fargate).  Docker images are loaded into ECR and ECS is fully setup using CloudFormation templates.

After deployments are done (new image loaded and/or any CloudFormation changes applied) I need to restart the service only if it's not running the latest version of the image that the Task Definition uses.  If CloudFormation updated the service or task definition then it will automatically restart and I don't want to restart it again.  Also, if the docker image was not deployed then I don't want to restart it.  So, is there a way to check what version of an image a service task is currently running?
I can't check if the version of a task definition changed because most of the time it would just be the image that changes and not the task definition.  I am loading the image using the Latest tag so I can just call ForceNewDeployment on the service to have it deploy the new version, but if it's possible I don't want to do that if nothing has changed.

I initially thought of trying to keep track of it in the deployment process but due to how our release pipeline is setup and some of the limits in Azure DevOps that's not something I'll be able to do.

I think the best solution, if it's possible, would be to check to see what version of an Image is currently running for each task in a service and if an image has an updated version then do a ForceNewDeployment on the service.  But...is there a way to accomplish that?  Or would there be a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Edit: When I load the Docker image to ECR I'm adding two tags: "Latest" and the DevOps release number ("1234").  I was initially hoping to just query the ECR images at the end of a release and if one has a tag with the current release number then I know the image has been updated.  The issue is that I don't know if the service was already restarted due to a CloudFormation change.

Comment: Why don't you want to restart the containers?  Can you change to some other versioning scheme that doesn't use the `latest` tag, so that the system can tell that you actually are trying to deploy a new version of an image?

Comment: Restarting the containers is possible, I was just trying to prevent unnecessary restarts or multiple restarts in a short time if possible.  That may be the only option though.  The issue with changing the labeling on the Image is that when a new image is loaded then I'd have to create a new Task Definition to point to that new image and then update the service to use that new Task Definition.  Using Latest is nice because I can just load the image and then force new deployment on the service.